# Ng-repeat through different objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m trying do ng-repeat with two different objects. In this case I want to return "*Name:Leanne Graham, Name: Asier*". The JSON file has this.

```
   users: {
       0: {
          email: "Sincere@april.biz",
          id: 1,
          name: "Leanne Graham",
          phone: "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
          username: "Bret",
          website: "hildegard.org"
       },
       1: {
          name: "Asier"
       }
   };
```

The element who has two objects is $scope.user and I try this

```
 <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in user">{{name}}</div>
```

Nothing happens, and no errors in console.log.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Angular is probably interpreting it as plain text and not parsing it

Comment: In addition to what @Phil said, you should probably fix the syntax error in your HTML snippet (**hint**: look at the way you've surrounded `name`).

Comment: I fix it json, the old example is a placehold of file. I paste the correct file in my question and repair copy-paste mistakes. But the "error" continue.

Comment: That's still not valid JSON or ever a valid JavaScript object literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your data is actually in a valid format, repeating over the collection seems simple enough...

```js
// note: this is just an example to put your data in scope
angular.module('so', []).run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.user = {
    0: {
      email: "Sincere@april.biz",
      id: 1,
      name: "Leanne Graham",
      phone: "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
      username: "Bret",
      website: "hildegard.org"
    },
    1: {
      name: "Asier"
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="so">
  <div ng-repeat="usr in user">{{usr.name}}</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Stupid error. Apart of json error (I use firebase so json is correct, the incorrect is copy-paste), ng-repeat has same two values `ng-repeat="user in user"`. Can´t have same values in ng-repeat, changing one, works fine. Thanks Phil.

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre that's why my answer has `usr in user`